# SSL with CartThrob - in-template redirect or htaccess on the basis of URL segment?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, expressionengine, cartthrob

this is a broader question than I would probably ask of the CartThrob folks, which is why I'm posting it here.  What would the community recommend as far as SSL is concerned with CartThrob? The store functions are limited to a couple of key template groups. So my thinking was perhaps the best way to handle it would be htaccess on the basis of the presence of those URL segments.  I would like to return the user to a non-SSL connection when they are not in the store area.  So a trigger might be the first segment being "basket" or "account" for example. Or what about an in-template redirect to the secure URL? Very interested to hear the community's suggestions on how best to handle SSL within a given area of an EE site.  I'm interested in whatever makes the most sense to implement, while also ensuring that, for example, all assets - even those loaded with path variables - are loaded via SSL.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I've always used CartThrob's `https_redirect` tag ([docs](http://cartthrob.com/legacy_docs/tags_detail/https_redirect)) on my checkout screens, which will rewrite your `{path}`, `{permalink}` (etc)-created URLs to use **https**, as well as redirect you to the **https://** version of your page if necessary.

That, combined with using the protocol-agnostic style of calling scripts and stylesheets should get you most of the way in getting your secure icon in the browser.

(Example:)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I remember being told by Cartthrob that they have deprecated that tag and you should use an htaccess solution. I can't remember the reason, though.

Comment: Yeah, I spoke with Chris Newton a couple of weeks ago and he mentioned that they had depreciated that tag, so I was figuring another solution might be a stronger bet. I figured the community will have done it in various ways before, so it would be worth asking.